# node js aws-sdk connect

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I have a s3 bucket like `aruba-get-rds-backups.getaws.arubanetworks.com/sp/` where `aruba-get-rds-backups.getaws.arubanetworks.com` is a bucket name and /sp is kind of sub folder how to access a file inside /sp folder in the bucket using getObject method of aws-sdk in nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function getS3Obj(bucketName, bucketKey) {
    let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    let s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" }); // provide credentials, if needed

    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: bucketKey,
    };
    let content = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    // assuming here you're downloading ascii file
    return content.Body!==undefined ? content.Body.toString() : null;
}

( async () =>{

    try {
        
        // your call will likely to be something...
        const content = await getS3Obj("bucketName", "sp/file.txt");
        console.log(content);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: good point I'll edit the return statement